# ie7 BUG : padding left and right with direction rtl

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm create a web page with direction rtl . when id set padding-right for a inline element like span , the padding set for left side in IE7 !!

HTML :

```
<div dir='rtl'>
    <span style='padding-right:30px;background:red'>Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the `<div dir="">` all about?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="direction: rtl;"></div>
```

or

```
<bdo dir="rtl"></bdo>
```

I believe you're using the property incorrectly. See the www3 specs --- > [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp) and [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_bdo.asp)